# Error importing beautifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, pip

I am having a weird error while importing bs4.
I could not find any help elsewhere.
I tried installing html and future.

complete traceback :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\bs4\__init__.py", line 35, in <module>
    from .builder import builder_registry, ParserRejectedMarkup
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\bs4\builder\__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from bs4.element import (
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py", line 10, in <module>
    from bs4.dammit import EntitySubstitution
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\bs4\dammit.py", line 53, in <module>
    class EntitySubstitution(object):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\bs4\dammit.py", line 74, in EntitySubstitution
    CHARACTER_TO_HTML_ENTITY_RE) = _populate_class_variables()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\bs4\dammit.py", line 62, in _populate_clas
s_variables
    character = chr(codepoint)
ValueError: chr() arg not in range(256)
```

Comment: which line, in which file?

Comment: I just invoked the command prompt and typed import bs4

Comment: Any help? I am completely lost...have tried everything...

Comment: Of course you've not tried everything -)) But just wait until I've inspect those lines.

Comment: Try reinstalling the module `pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall beautifulsoup4`

Comment: The reinstall failed...

Comment: In case you have more that one version of Python installed in that computer, make sure you have used the correct pip version. For Python3, it usually is `pip3 install`.

Answer (score 0):

1. Try this

   ```
     from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
   ```

   Works with python3 and BS 4 aswell
2. Or Maybe this helps:

   ```
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
    import urllib
    url="http://example.com"
    soup = bs(urllib.urlopen(url))
    for link in soup.findAll('a'):
    print link.string
   ```

   To get any data of tag just replace the "a" with the tag you want
3. Cross check if filename is named "bs4.py" or maybe something like "HTMLParser.py"

Comment: Nope the exact same traceback

Answer (score 0):

> [The reinstall failed..](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43735393/error-importing-beautifulsoup/43736012#comment74513906_43735393)

Since `pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall beautifulsoup4` failed for you. I'm guessing there are multiple versions of python installed in your system OR the module was not installed properly.

You should try uninstalling the module first by `pip uninstall <module>` and then do a fresh install `pip install <module>`